# Why would a generated Package from axis2 includes extra "src"?

Tags: java, ant, apache-axis

I'm attempting to convert an application from JaxB to Axis2 as I have a working example of it to base off of, but I'm currently having an issue with it generating through my sharedbuild.xml file.

The source code in the shared build looks like this:

```
<property name="gen.source.dir" value="${source.dir}/gen" />

<target name="axis build" depends="ivy.retrieve.tools">
    <mkdir dir="${gen.source.dir}" description="ensures output directory is available"/>
    <delete dir="${gen.source.dir}/com/company/rce/axis2" />
    <taskdef name="codegen" classname="org.apache.axis2.tool.ant.AntCodegenTask">
        <classpath>
            <fileset dir="tools\axis2-ant-plugin" includes="*.jar"/>
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>
    <codegen
    wsdlfilename=wsdl address
    output="${gen.source.dir}"
    packageName="com.company.rce.axis"
    generateservicexml="true"/>
</target>
```

I've replace my company with company in the package name and the wsdl with "wsdl address" but my problem lies in the fact that in my src/gen folder, the package comes out as "src.com.company.rce.axis".  I've been working on this for a couple days now and this has completely stonewalled me.  Is there a place you see or you would know that would cause src to be concatenated on to the beginning of the packageName?

Comment: Does the extra src happen with other WSDL files?

Comment: Yes, I just ran http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx?wsdl and it still gives me "src.com.company.rce.axis" and not "com.company.rce.axis" in the src/gen folder

Answer (score 1):

The best way to generate Java code from wdsl and avoid src subfolder is using maven axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin as well

```
<properties>
    <axis2.version>1.7.4</axis2.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-kernel</artifactId>
        <version>${axis2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-adb</artifactId>
        <version>${axis2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-transport-http</artifactId>
        <version>${axis2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-transport-local</artifactId>
        <version>${axis2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-xmlbeans</artifactId>
        <version>${axis2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${axis2.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdl2code</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <wsdlFile>src/main/resources/static/EXAMPLE.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                        <!-- Valid values are xmlbeans, adb, jibx, and none -->
                        <databindingName>xmlbeans</databindingName>
                        <packageName>com.example</packageName>
                        <outputDirectory>src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                        <flattenFiles>true</flattenFiles>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Nice! @AgustíSánchez

Answer (score 0):

Check your WSDL for `xmlns:src="someuri"`. Then add this to your `codegen` task: `namespaceToPackages="someuri=com.company.rce.axis"`. Make sure to replace "someuri" with whatever is in your actual WSDL file.

Comment: I have not found a namespace of src in the wsdl, these were my options to choose from: wsdl, wsam, wsx, wsap, msc, wsp, xsd, soap, soap12, soapenc, tns, wsa10, wsaw, wsu, wsa

Comment: Seems like it must be something related to `namespaceToPackages`, but I'm baffled about where else to look.